# PHP: DOM get url and anchors (but not IMG)

Tags: php, url, dom, hyperlink

I want to select all URL's from a HTML page into an array like:

```
This is a webpage <a href="http://somesite.com/link1.php">with</a> 
different kinds of <a href="http://somesite.com/link1.php"><img src="someimg.png"></a>
```

The output i would like is:

```
with => http://somesite.se/link1.php
```

Now i get:

```
<img src="someimg.png"> => http://somesite.com/link1.php
with => http://somesite.com/link1.php
```

I do not want the urls/links that does contain a image between the start  and end . Only the ones with text.

My current code is:

```
<?php

function innerHTML($node) {
    $ret = '';

    foreach ($node->childNodes as $node) {
        $ret .= $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node);
    }

    return $ret;
}

$html = file_get_contents('http://somesite.com/'.$_GET['apt']);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html); // @ = Removes errors from the HTML...
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$result = array();

foreach ($links as $link) {
    //$node = $link->nodeValue;
    $node = innerHTML($link);
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');

    if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $href))
            $result[$node] = $href;
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a second `preg_match` to your conditional:

```
if(preg_match('/\.pdf$/i',$href) && !preg_match('/<img .*>/i',$node)) $result[$node] = $href;
```